# Devexpress Calendar control keeps loading

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, calendar, devexpress

I am using *Devexpress* Calendar control to disable some dates and change there Text Value, i.e I am changing the dates that are less than 10 by concatenating a leading 0 with them. e.g from 1, 2, 3 to 01, 02, 03 and so on. for this purpose i am triggering it's Cell Initialize and Cell Prepared Event. it does work fine but when i navigate to another month it keeps on `loading` why is it doing so?
kindly suggest alternatives if it's not going to be solved this way.

**My Code So far:** 
**C# Codebehind:**

```
protected void ASPxDateEdit1_CalendarDayCellPrepared(object sender, CalendarDayCellPreparedEventArgs e)
    {
        int Date;
        bool isValidDate = int.TryParse(e.Date.Day.ToString(), out Date);
        if (isValidDate)
        {
            if (Date > 0 && Date < 10)
            {
                e.Cell.Text = "0" + e.Date.Day.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

**ASPX:**

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ClientInstanceName="ASPxPopupClientControl" Width="300px" Height="150px"
    MaxWidth="800px" MaxHeight="300px" MinHeight="150px" MinWidth="150px" ID="pcMain"
    ShowFooter="True" FooterText="HolidayIn" PopupElementID="d1" HeaderText="Select Date From"
    runat="server" EnableViewState="false" PopupHorizontalAlign="LeftSides" PopupVerticalAlign="Below" EnableHierarchyRecreation="True">
    <ContentCollection>
        <dx:PopupControlContentControl runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="color: #666666;">
                            <div style="float: left">
                                <dx:ASPxCalendar ID="ASPxCalendar" EnableTheming="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="MainHeader" CssClass="Align"
                                    HeaderStyle-Paddings-PaddingLeft="70px" HeaderStyle-Cursor="pointer" ShowDayHeaders="true" ShowClearButton="false" ShowTodayButton="false"
                                    TodayButtonText="Today's Date" RootStyle-Wrap="True" DayStyle-CssClass="DayStyle" ShowWeekNumbers="false" Height="200px" Width="300px"
                                    HighlightWeekends="true" HighlightToday="true" DayHeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" Theme="Office2003Blue" runat="server"
                                    DayDisabledStyle-BackColor="White" DayDisabledStyle-Font-Strikeout="true" OnDayCellPrepared="ASPxDateEdit1_CalendarDayCellPrepared">
                                </dx:ASPxCalendar>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
    </ContentCollection>
    <ClientSideEvents CloseUp="function(s, e) { SetImageState(false); }" PopUp="function(s, e) { SetImageState(true); }" />
</dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

Here is how it looks when it keeps loading and gets stuck there:
[image: Picture]

**NOTE:** I am trying to align my date cell of calendar control as they don't remain proper on the page. I am attaching snapshots too.

 
**Correct Formatted Calendar Control:**

[image: Correct]

**Incorrect Formatted Calendar Control:**

[image: Incorrect]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your calendar manipulation is being called when you don't want it to. To prevent your event from firing when you don't want it to, wrap it in a bool set to false when you don't want it to fire, and true when you do. Something like:

```
bool isLoading = true;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if(isPostBack){
            isLoading = true;
            //do your other form loading stuff
            isLoading=false;
       // }

    }
 protected void ASPxDateEdit1_CalendarDayCellPrepared(object sender, CalendarDayCellPreparedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!isLoading)
    {
        isLoading = true;
        int Date;
        bool isValidDate = int.TryParse(e.Date.Day.ToString(), out Date);
        if (isValidDate)
        {
            if (Date > 0 && Date < 10)
            {
                e.Cell.Text = "0" + e.Date.Day.ToString();
            }
        }
        isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't worked, besides `bool isLoading` I even tried `ViewState` also.

Comment: but yes i think it is being triggered every time when we navigate to next month

Comment: To test, you can de-register ASPxDateEdit1_CalendarDayCellPrepared and tie it to a button click - see if that solves the problem. If it does, then it's a matter of finding when ASPxDateEdit1_CalendarDayCellPrepared fires and preventing it from doing so when you don't want it to.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that also. but still it gets stuck. one thing i think is compulsory to mention which is, when the page is sent postback after it is stuck in loading process, then it works fine

Comment: Hmmm- maybe try removing the IF/POSTBACK from the load event (see edited answer)

Comment: well, let me do that either

Comment: It also failed . maybe i think i should call this in another thread or in background worker but i am not sure

Comment: Somehow, isLoading is getting set to true. My guess is that something is triggering the event from outside the form_load method. If you want to paste your entire page code, I'll help if I can. Otherwise, it's on you to fire up the debugger to maximum and go through things step by step

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by using another Control offered by devexpress but it the calendar control never worked! I Used *ASPxDateEdit* Control.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Sorry I couldn't help you - but it wasn't for a lack of trying. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah thanks to you at least you tried to help me out. Cheers!